# How can I clean everything after the code?

Tags: java, exit

I have a program that is run by an external software. The first run is always successful. The second run causes the hanging of my software because there is something left from the previous run (some objects, some processes). I cannot find what is left. It seems to me that I clean properly but apparently I am wrong.

Is there an efficient way to stop and clean everything? I cannot use `exit(0)` since it will kill the external software.

**ADDED**

I use Java interface to communicate between my and the external software. Something like that:

```
mySoftware = new MySoftware(parameters);
my.Software.start();
my.Software.stop();
```

Comment: Maybe looking at a strace might give some clues?

Comment: You will need to provide more information. How is your program run by external software? I presume they are running in the same JVM since exit(0) kills both applications.

Answer (score 2):

General approaches to find the leaking resource:

- Use a profiler like VisualVM to show the memory usage of your program.
- Stop the app with Ctrl+Break and examine what threads are running, and which may be in deadlocked state.
- Put debug statements in the code to detect where it hangs.
- Run it through static code analysis tools like FindBugs which might be able identify resources not freed correctly.

Finding and removing the root cause of the problem is IMHO always preferable over treating the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do some testing/debugging/[(resource-)logging](http://www.slf4j.org/)/[memory-profiling](http://visualvm.java.net/)/[static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java)/[pluggable type-checking](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/) to find the cause and then remove it.

If you are doing tests and the "something left" might be a file, then you can check this easily by using [junit's TemporaryFolder-rule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html), see [e.g. this introduction](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/junit-tip-use-rules-to-manage-temporary-files-and-folders/).

Answer (score 0):

You could start with running the [Google singleton detector](http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/) on your code and checking that your cleanup code also takes care of the singleton instances.

As a followup you could have a look at refactoring those singleton instances that don't really have to be singletons and replace them with code using dependency injection instead (allocating the object to use and passing it on via the construstors of instances used is often a better solution.)

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to assign null to objects that you create at the end of the code. It can be placed in finally block if there are any try/catch blocks. This will not immediately clean up the objects from memory area, but it will let the garbage collector know that these objects can be cleaned up.

Example code for you.

```
try{
HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet1 = workBook.createSheet("Log_Report");
HashMap<Integer, HSSFRow> hashMapRow = new HashMap<Integer, HSSFRow>();
...
}
catch{}{
...
}
finally{
sheet1=null;
workBook=null;
hashMapRow=null;
}
```

Comment: No, this practice is unnecessary and is just cluttering the code. As the references have local scope, they cease to exist anyway at the point of returning from the method call, so the GC will know that the objects aren't referenced anymore.